# PHP: вывод количества записей в каждой категории

Tags: php, sqlite3

Нужно, казалось бы, простую вещь реализовать — вывести на странице списка категорий, возле каждой категории число относимых к ней статей. Вот моя попытка, но тщетно (это функция, которая выводит список всех категорий):

```
//Показать все категории
function categories() {
    $db = new SQLite3(DB_NAME);
    $results = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM articles");
    $articles = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM articles WHERE category LIKE '%$category%'");
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        echo 'Категория: <a href="?category=' . $row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</a> Статей: (' . $articles . ')';
    }
  $db->close();
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка и как её исправить.

Comment: `var_dump($articles);` в студию

Comment: int(7)  вот так вот))

Comment: а, я понял в чем косяк, ща

Comment: А в один запрос, используя `GROUP BY` не судьба?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как-то так:

```
//Показать все категории
function categories() {
    $db = new SQLite3(DB_NAME);
    $results = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM articles");
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        $articles = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM articles WHERE category LIKE '%".$row['category']."%'");
        echo 'Категория: <a href="?category=' . $row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</a> Статей: (' . $articles . ')';
    }
  $db->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> PHP: вывод количества записей в каждой категории

Экономить на вызовах к базе данных, более оптимальный вариант:

```
//Показать все категории
function categories() {
    $db = new SQLite3(DB_NAME);
    // Один вызов со всем что нужно
    $results = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT category, COUNT(category) as count FROM articles Group by category");
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {   
        echo 'Категория: <a href="?category=' . $row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</a> Статей: (' . $row['count'] . ')';
    }
  $db->close();
}
```

---

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c14b9a/2